# Middle English: y or ȝ

Tags: english, etymology, transcription, alphabets, old-english

Lately I've been looking up the Middle English of many Modern English words via Wiktionary. It was my understanding that by this point in the history of English ȝ was in heavy use. Yet these etymologies almost always use a y instead.

I understand that written English was far from standardized. Wiktionary generally shows several forms commonly used, yet often will show a y-option and no ȝ-option. For example,

wynd

> ### Middle English
>
> #### Etymology 1
>
> From Old English *wind*, from Proto-West Germanic **wind*, from Proto-Germanic **windaz*.
>
> #### Alternative forms
>
> wend, wende, wind, winde, wynde
>
> #### Pronunciation
>
> IPA: /wiːnd/, /wind/

I've also used Etymonline, but it rarely sites "alternative forms," so it's even less helpful on this issue.

**So, if I see a y-option, can I assume there was also a ȝ-option?**

---

As I'm still not understanding I'll add a more informative example:

rail

> #### Etymology 1
>
> From Middle English From Middle English *rail*, *rayl*, **reȝel*, **reȝol* (found in *reȝolsticke* (“a ruler”)), partly from Old English *regol* (“a ruler, straight bar”) and partly from Old French *reille*; both from Latin *regula* (“rule, bar”), from *regere* (“to rule, to guide, to govern”)
>
> #### Pronunciation
>
> IPA: /ɹeɪl/, [ɹeɪɫ]

way

> #### Etymology 1
>
> From Middle English *way*, *wey*, from Old English *weġ* (“way; path”), from Proto-West Germanic **weg*, from Proto-Germanic **wegaz*, from Proto-Indo-European **weǵʰ-*. Doublet of *voe*.
>
> #### Alternative forms
>
> waye, waie (both obsolete)
>
> #### Pronunciation
>
> IPA: /weɪ/

Both rail and way rhyme and both come from an Old English predecessor containing a g, yet both do not include ME spellings containing a yogh (on Wiktionary). So, if I wanted to say "railway" (on a sign in a fantasy medieval game) I'm unsure if "raȝelwaȝ" is appropriate.

Comment: If this question is more appropriate to a different Stack Exchange, please don't hesitate to let me know

Comment: As opposed to the same sites' copious display of [thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)), for instance ? As it currently stands, the question basically seems to ask why some internet sites (about linguistics) use standard ASCII notation, instead of fancy UTF or Unicode symbols, for (transliterating) certain out of use letters; to which the answer seems somewhat obvious : for the same reason most other internet sites, on any other given topic, favor the same standard option.

Comment: ȝ was a _consonant_ letter, not a vowel, it couldn't be used in ‘wynd’. Start with this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogh

Comment: Via that same article (which I had already read much of), "Phonetic usage  [g], [j], [ŋ], [ɣ], [x], [ç], [i], [ʃ], [ʎ], [ð], /joʊɡ/"

Comment: I think you should consider using https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you, that's very useful

Comment: This question is explained very clearly in [Scragg 1974 *A History of English Spelling*](https://manchesteruniversitypress.co.uk/9780719006395/a-history-of-english-spelling/), pp. 22-23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yellow Sky notes in the comments, yogh was a *consonant*, not a vowel. It was originally used to represent `/g/`; eventually certain sounds that used to be allophones of `/g/` became their own phonemes (notably `/j/` and `/x/`), and yogh is most famously used for these.

*Wynd*, though, doesn't have a `/j/`, a `/x/`, or any other `/g/`-related sound in it. The *y* in this spelling is a full vowel `/i/`, and yogh wasn't used for that.

Even when it was used for `/j/` and `/x/`, though, yogh was never universal. *Gh* was also fairly common in the Middle English period for `/x/`, and *y* for `/j/`. Wiktionary often lists [spellings with yogh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/y%C8%9De#Middle_English) as [alternate forms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ni%C8%9Dt#Middle_English); this might be because the forms with yogh are actually less common in the manuscripts (so they're considered the "alternate" spellings rather than the "primary" ones), or because they're simply harder to typeset and so modern scholars of Middle English prefer the easier ones. I don't know enough about Middle English orthography to say.

Comment: As far as I remember, /x/ was not an allophone of /g/, /ɣ/ was. /x/ was an allophone of /h/.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM I believe the two merged by Middle English, hence MidE _niȝt_ < OE _niht_ "night".

Comment: (It would be more correct to talk about ɣ being the allophone and then x merging with it later, but that seemed like it added a lot of complication for not much benefit.)

Comment: I see, but I feel like /ɣ/ didn't last long and was lost in most positions, such as ModE fowl > OE fugol.

Comment: I don’t think yogh was ever regularly used for /g/. In Old English when /g/ was regularly represented by the Insular g, that did represent both /g/ and its allophones [ɣ x ɣʲ ɣʷ], but by the time the shape of the Insular g had morphed into what we now call yogh around the shift to Middle English, the hard g had been reintroduced both phonemically and orthographically, and /g/ (now no longer allophonic with the fricatives) was represented by the ‘new’, non-Insular g. If yogh (as opposed to Insular g) ever represented /g/, it can’t have been for long.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There also I'm simplifying a bit to make the explanation shorter—in particular I'm using the same name for Old English "insular g" and Middle English "yogh" since they're effectively the same glyph at two different stages in its history.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding because I've never understood this concept of "y as a consonant." To me "y" has never sounded or felt (i.e., there's no point of articulation) like a consonant.

Comment: @RubelliteFae The short explanation is that "vowels" form the nucleus of a syllable and "consonants" don't. (Also, there is a place of articulation: it's palatal. There's just not a complete closure, since it's an approximant, like /w/, /ɹ/, etc.)

Comment: I guess for the same reason I've only ever thought of /ɾ/ & /r/ as consonants and not /ɹ/ (or /w/). I don't really understand this "nucleus of a syllable" concept. For example, the first syllable of "syllable" contains the consonants /s/ & /ɫ/. Which is the nucleus and why? And if one is the nucleus and not the other, then why are both considered consonants? The whole thing sounds much more convoluted to me than simply calling the sounds made by contact of two mouthparts consonants and the sounds not made in this way vowels. Also, I've updated the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RubelliteFae Neither /s/ nor /l is the nucleus of the first syllable in _syllable_ – the /ɪ/ between them is. Lots of consonants don’t have contact between different parts of the mouth – several fricatives and all approximants. That doesn’t make them vowels if they behave like other consonants. Sounds like /x/ and /ʀ/ in German and French, for example, generally have no contact, but are not vowels. The same is true of English /r/. Meanwhile, /l̩/ and /n̩/ as in _syllab*le*_ and _butt*on*_ are vowels (syllable peaks) despite full contact.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet OP said the nucleus of the syllable is the consonant, but /ɪ/ is a vowel. Along with what else you and others have said I'm coming away from this question feeling far more confused than before I asked.

Comment: @RubelliteFae No, you have that backwards – he said that _vowels_ form the nucleus, consonants don’t. That’s the least controversial definition of what is a consonant and what is a vowel (but there are always going to be grey areas – ultimately, neither consonants, vowels or syllables have definitions that fit all languages).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, you are right. I read them incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, so I understand ȝ for /ɣ/ and /x/, but I still don't understand ȝ /j/. It's just a dipthong (/i/+/ɑ/), yes? And thus still a vowel? As for g, does this mean that ȝ was used by some people and g by others? Or did g come later entirely?

Comment: @RubelliteFae /j/ in English is very often the result of /g/ before a front vowel. In Old English, /ge, gi/ (often written with a dot over the g when representing OE in modern texts) became [je, ji] due to palatalisation. In other cases, /j/ was an inherited /j/ that had never been a /g/ (like in _year_), but because yogh was commonly used to represent all the allophones of /g/, including the palatalised [j], it also became used in cases where there had never been a /g/, because speakers/writers at the time didn’t know that the [j] in _year_ was different from the one in _yesterday_.

Comment: Sequences like [ja, je] are not normally considered diphthongs in English, but consonant + vowel. However, the reverse sequences [aɪ eɪ] are considered diphthongs (and therefore written with the vowel sign ɪ instead of the consonant sign j). Historically, <g> came after yogh – the Insular g (which evolved into yogh) was how /g/ was originally written, but once [g] and [ɣ x j w] stopped being allophones of the same phoneme, they needed a way to write the new /g/ phoneme, and they used the French-style <g>. But this was a process that took time; things were less organised back then.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see. So /j/ = /i/+vowel, but /j/ isn't considered a vowel (nor diphthong) because of its historical development, right? I'm not sure what palletization means (I would have assumed shift from velar locus to palatal, but /j/ is the result of moving the tongue from the front of the mouth to the back, so I'm not following here), but to my ear and tongue /g/ is very different to /j/. It always starts as /i/ or /ɪ/, so I don't understand why they would have written g or y instead of i or j. I'm not disputing it, there's just clearly a piece of the puzzle I'm still missing.

Comment: @RubelliteFae Palletisation is putting things on pallets, but _palatalisation_ is indeed moving a sound towards the palate. /j/ is a palatal sound since its place of articulation is the palate: that’s where the gap between the tongue and the ‘rim’ of the oral cavity is smallest. /j/ is not “the result of moving the tongue from the front of the mouth to the back”. /g/ is velar and plosive, so very different from /j/, yes, but in OE, a /g/ before a front vowel **became** /j/ over time, through a process of palatalisation, going something like /ge > gʲe > ɟe > je/. This is quite common.

Comment: You can’t really say that /j/ = /i/ + vowel in English, either. There are minimal pairs between /jV/ and /iV/. Not so much in modern English, but plenty in Old English where it’s the difference between <g̍e> and <īe>, for example – and you even get <g̍īe> /jie/, which has both in one. It’s easier to just consider them separate phonemes as far as English is concerned.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Okay, not the front of the mouth to the back, but front of the mouth to the middle. I can literally feel my tongue do this. Are you saying that I'm the only person who makes /j/ this way? As for all that extended IPA, I have no clue what that's about. I'm obviously not a professional linguist. It feels like your purposefully talking over my head—to what end, I have no idea. Anyway, I can't hear any difference between /iɛs/ and /jɛs/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm getting notifications that comments shouldn't be used for extended discussion (and this has already veered off from the main question, which Alex best answered with his referral to the dictionary at quod.lib.umich.edu). So, perhaps you can link me to a video that explains your points, as audio/video would seem to be the better media for learning about the finer differences between phonemes. Thanks

Comment: @RubelliteFae There is definitely a difference between /ie/ and /je/. The first is rare in Modern English because the Middle English diphthong /ie/ has become /iə/ with a schwa, while /je/ has remained. It’s easier to find pairs with /iə/ vs /jə/, such as the difference between _can Ian_ /kan iən/ and _canyon_ /kanjən/. As for the production of /j/, the tongue does not move backwards at all. You lift the middle of the tongue up towards the hard palate, and that’s where it stays for the duration of /j/. Once you move it away from there, you’re no longer saying /j/ but some vowel following it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks so much for that explanation about tongue positions. I had to say a lot of different words to feel the slight difference, but I understand now. I am a native speaker, but (I think) when I produce /j/ the middle of my tongue moves up much less than other speakers and I do start the sound with a slight /i/ (i.e., my /j/ is actually more of a /ij/). However, I also speak Japanese and when I compared my use of /j/ to /i/ in Japanese it was immediately clear. This issue had been confusing me since I first took a linguistics class 15 years ago. So, thanks ♥